# Validation Rule with both AND/OR logic

Tags: validation

I need to require the Length of SOW field to be entered if the opp is not in Long Range Forecast or Discovery stage. If I just have one of the stages in the formula, it fires just as expected. Once I add in the OR with the other stage, it does not fire as expected and is requiring the field to be entered for all stages.

```
OR( 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Long Range Forecast")) , 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Discovery")), 
AND( 
ISBLANK( Length_of_SOW_Months__c )) 
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logical condition is wrong. You will have to use AND condition with negation of the both the stage values like below.

```
AND( /* This ensures all the condition are met*/
    ISBLANK( Length_of_SOW_Months__c ),
    TEXT(StageName)<>"Discovery",
    TEXT(StageName)<>"Long Range Forecast"
 )
```

**Edit: Based on Adrians Comments**

Its also ideal to reduce the the reference count to picklist as were checking for stage name multiple times, so we can leverage **`CASE`** function here.

```
AND(ISBLANK( Length_of_SOW_Months__c ),
    CASE(StageName,
        "Discovery", 1,
        "Long Range Forecast", 1,
        0)=0
    )
```